# Expected values of $X^mY^n$ if $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

As we know, if $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables, then one can show that $\operatorname {E} [XY]=\operatorname {E} [X]\operatorname {E} [Y]$. Under this assumption, is it still true that $\operatorname {E} [X^mY^n]=\operatorname {E} [X^m]\operatorname {E} [Y^n]$?

Comment: yes, it is true too

Comment: More generally $Ef(X)g(Y)=Ef(X)Eg(Y)$ whenever $f$ and $g$ are measurable and the expectations exist. This is  because $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are also independent r.v.'s.

Comment: Ok, it is clear. Thank you!!